# Find sum of the gaps in array, assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly

I'm am stuck like crazy on this question. We're supposed to find the sum of the gaps in our array. I've got the code written to find the sum of the array but no idea how to find the sum of the gaps. Here's what I have. So the gaps are 2,3,4,1 and the sum should be 10.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    array DWORD 0,2,5,9,10  
.code
main proc
    mov edi,OFFSET array
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF array
    mov eax,0

L1:
    add eax,[edi]
    add edi,TYPE array
    loop L1

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: You get a gap by subtracting two values. Your loop should be one shorter than the number of items, as the gaps are one less than the number of items.

Comment: Just saw your response, still getting use to the site. I'm not sure how to make the loop shorter. Wouldn't it be something like mov ecx, LENGTHOF array/1?

Comment: The sum of the gaps is just the last element minus the first, unless you're talking about the absolute value of the gaps, in which case it won't be that if the numbers aren't increasing.

Comment: In this case the sum should be 10, the gaps are 2,3,4,1 as given by the book.

Comment: Right. Which is the same as the last element 10 minus the first element 0. What I'm saying is to compute the sum of the gaps, you only need to subtract the first element from the last. That's because the sum of the gaps is `(a1 - a0) + (a2 - a1) + ... + (aN - aN-1)` and all the terms in the middle cancel, leaving you with `aN - a0`.

Comment: The sum of the gaps is just the last element minus the first, unless you're talking about the absolute value of the gaps, in which case it won't be true *if the numbers aren't monotonically increasing*. But if you're required to do this the long way, note that `loop` just decrement `ecx`. It does not auto-increment your array pointer. You've loaded `edi` with the offset of `array`, so why not use `lodsd` to load `eax` with each successive element, and `edi` will automatically increment. Set aside a different registers (besides `eax`) for your running sum and the last element read.

Comment: I get what you're saying, makes sense in this case. Not sure how to implement it though Edit: We havn't used lodsd yet, not sure how to use that.

Comment: Just look it up. All the documentation for these instructions online. Google "x86 lods". Are you allowed to use it? And I was a little mistaken: `lods` instructions assume the pointer is `esi` not `edi`. But it does auto-increment.

Comment: I wouldn't think we could use something we haven't covered yet but I guess I can google it and see what I find.

Comment: @megagig: Dividing by 1 doesn't change the value, you should subtract: `mov ecx, LENGTHOF array - 1`. (I don't know what's allowed in the syntax though, you might need some parentheses in there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long way to find the sum of gaps:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    array DWORD 0,2,5,9,10  
.code
main proc
    mov esi,OFFSET array
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF array
    mov ebx,0                ; Start sum at 0
    cld                      ; Clear the direction bit (look up the LODS instruction!)
    lodsd                    ; Get the first value to start
    mov edx, eax             ; Save "previous" element read in edx
    dec ecx                  ; Decrement the loop counter 'cuz we read one
L1:
    lodsd
    sub ebx, edx             ; sum = sum + (this element - prev element)
    add ebx, eax             ; or, sum = sum - prev, then sum = sum + this
    mov edx, eax             ; save previous element in edx
    loop L1

    mov eax, ebx             ; put the result in eax
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

If you're required to do it the long way, but not allowed to use `lodsd`, then I leave it as an exercise to convert your loop to not using `lodsd`.

The short way is to realize that the sum of the gaps is:

```
(a[1] - a[0]) + (a[2] - a[1]) + ... + (a[N] - a[N-1])
```

Which, assuming you aren't taking the absolute value of the differences, is just: `a[N] - a[0]`. That can be computed as follows (NOTE: I'm not sure of MASM syntax here for array + offset, so you may have to modify a little):

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    array DWORD 0,2,5,9,10  
.code
main proc
    mov ebx, LENGTHOF array
    dec ebx                  ; last element is at length-1 index
    shl ebx, 2               ; length * 4 for size of DWORD
    mov eax, [array + ebx]   ; read last element
    sub eax, [array]         ; subtract first element

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: wow thanks. tbh I like the first example better but I checked and the lodsd isn't covered in our class for a few more weeks so I don't know if it would be accepted. It doesn't say absolute values so I assume that doesn't matter. Thanks for all your help, and the the comments explaining what does what as well. Assembly is going to take me a lot more time to understand than c++ did.

Comment: @megagig, I think, if you have to, you can convert the first example to discrete addresses. Look up what `lodsd` does and just mimic it. All it does is (1) move the contents of what `esi` points to into `eax`, and then (2) increment `esi` by the size of `eax` bytes (which is 4). It's real simple. Google search "MASM addressing modes" if needed.

Comment: I went ahead and looked ahead in our text to find out what losds does. It basically says it loads whatever is in esi into eax so in my mind all I should have to do is change lodsd to mov eax, esi but that doesn't work ;/

Comment: @lurker To clear the direction flag we use `CLD` ( not `CLI`). Probably a typo in your code :)

Comment: @megagig if you read my prior comment on this, I described what `lodsd` does. It loads *what `esi` points to* into `eax`*, **and** it increments `esi` by the size of `eax`, which is 4. If you do `mov eax, esi` you are moving the *contents* of `esi` into `eax`, not what `esi` points. to. Thus, I recommended googling MASM addressing modes.

Comment: I actually too that out because we haven't used that yet either. Also it works with just having lodsd in the loop and not the top. I'm just changing somethings around to learn and see what happens but doesn't seem related to cli that I can tell Edit: Ah I see the difference, thanks.

Comment: @megagig It *happens* to work without the first `lodsd` because the first value in the array is `0` and you probably already have `0` in `eax`. But the *correct* solution keeps the first `lodsd`. Remember that a program is not necessarily correct if it *happens* to work. :) The real key to understanding is to try to realize why each step is there. Removing something to see if it still works can be very deceiving.

Comment: The first version has a longer-than-necessary loop-carried dependency chain.  `sum += a[i+1]` / `sum -= a[i]` modifies `sum` twice, so the loop is limited by latency to running at one cycle per 2 iterations.  Doing `sum += (a[i+1] - a[i])` can run at one cycler per 1 iteration, if you keep the loop overhead low enough.  Keeping the "next" element in a register for use as the next iteration's "prev" element is nice, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have zero desire to refresh my assembly... but in the interest of getting you started, here's how I would do this in C (which has been called high level PDP-11 Assembler IIRC)

```
int array[5] = [0,2,5,9,10]
int sum = 0;
int length = 5;

for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
{
   sum += (array[i+1]-array[i]);
}
//sum is now equal to 10, 2 + 3 + 4 + 1
```

Comment: That sort of helps, I'll keep working at it. Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm still learning this sites code blocks

Comment: Note that technically, you could stick this in a c program (with a main wrapper) and do gcc -S (i think, maybe -s) to make it spit out assembly.  I would strongly discourage trying to use this directly as the instructions it's likely to use (especially with high optimization) will probably be rather whacky if you're just starting out with assembly

Comment: Yea I'm just starting in assembly. The issue is our text is just bad, the entire class hates the layout and there's really bad examples. I'm struggling with every assignment. I've taken vb, java, and c++ and assembly stinks compared. I'm still not getting this to work :/

Comment: You would read the `dword` from location `array + 4*4` (that's the base plus the size of `dword` (4) times the element index, where the first index is 0). Then subtract the `dword` that you read from location `array`.

Comment: bug: you wrote `array[0]`, not `array[i]`.

Comment: fixed (not that I even remembered this answer)

Answer (score -2):

```
Include Irvine32.inc

.data

array dword 0,2,5,7,9]              ; Array initializatiom

Sum dword 0                         ; variable containing sum

counter dword ?

.code

main proc

mov eax,0                         ; eax=0 because no garbage value is shown

mov esi,offset array              ; esi caontain array 1st index address
mov ecx,lengthof array-1          ; loop is repeated 4 times as two no are compared

  l1:

            add eax,[esi+4]                   ; eax have 2nd value of array
            sub eax,[esi]                     ; sub array 2nd and first value

            add esi,type array                ; Esi have next array value after each alteration 

            add sum,eax                       ; Sum is stored after each alteration

  loop l1

call writeint

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Did you test this?  The gap between two elements only depends on those elements, not on the old value of the gap, which you'd have noticed if you read the existing answers.  If you think you have something useful to add with a new answer, you should explain what's interesting about your code with text outside the code.

Comment: thanks for your concentration
I test this code this code generate the sum of all the difference betweeen two individual values  af array 
for example
if we have an array 0,3,5
than the difference between fist two elements is 3

Comment: But you `add eax, [esi+4]` instead of `mov eax, [esi+4]`.  So on the 2nd iteration, you're going to do `sum += 5`, not `sum += 2` in your 0,3,5 example.  That's what I meant by not depending on the old value of the gap.

Comment: thanks again 
let reconsider the example we have 3 array elements 0 , 3 , 5
* I use add eax,[ esi + 4 ] , as i use array of Dword and esi contain reference of first array value 
* So for reference of next array val I have to add 4 in first array value reference 
* So add eax,[ esi + 4 ]  move 2nd value of array which is 3 to eax register
*  second command sub eax,[esi] this command subtract the val that is on array first index from eax register 
At the end we add this value in sum that is 0

Comment: `add eax, [esi+4]` doesn't move the 2nd value, it adds to what's already there.  It happens to be zero only in the first iteration.  I think your code would be correct if you used `mov eax, [esi+4]` instead of `add`.

Comment: Dry run
1 mov esi , offset array
2 add  eax,[esi + 4]
3 sub eax , [esi]
4 add sum,eax
array 1,4,7,8,9
Step-1
* eax = 4
* eax = 4 - 1
* sum = 0 +3
* sum = 3
Step-2
* eax = 7
* eax = 7 - 4 =3
* sum =  sum + eax = 3 + 3 
* Sum =6..........
At the end we have  sum = 8

Comment: for my code after each alteration eax value become equal to 0

Comment: I ran your code.  `eax` holds the right answer.  `sum` doesn't.  With the `0, ..., 10` array, your loop finishes with `eax=10`, `sum=26`.

Comment: The code in your answer does `add sum, eax`, not `mov`.  That would also fix the code in your answer.  Are you sure the code in your answer matches what you're actually running?  Your last edit broke it, and I had to fix `Sum` vs. `sum` (upper-case vs. lower).  But I also had to port it to NASM.  I assume MASM is case-sensitive, too, though.

Comment: for your answer mov eax,[esi + 4]  we have to add this line in loop at the end  mov eax,sum........................................
l1:

            mov eax,[esi+4]    ..........................              
            sub eax,[esi]  ..................................................                   

            add esi,type array .......................................................   
  
add sum,eax.....................                       

   mov eax,sum..................            
  loop l1

Comment: Yeah, that would fix it.  I assumed the point of your function was to generate a value in `sum`.  If you're actually only trying to generate a value in `eax`, why does `sum` even exist?  Or, why not change the code in your answer to `mov [sum], eax` *after* the loop?

Comment: Since your "answer" only includes code, I had to guess about what it was supposed to do.  Since you were updating a global variable, I assumed that was the output, not `eax`.

Comment: i use because the subtracted answer should be added at end therefore i use sum variable..